# Underscore dynamic chaining

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, filtering, chaining

If I have a array of function that must be closures for _.filter method, how can I make this filter dynamically?

```
_filters : {
    shipped: function(order){ return order.get('is_shipped') },
    imported: function(order){ return order.get('is_imported') }
},
```

What I want is to have ability to dynamically create the chain like this

```
_.chain(orders).filter(filters.shipped).filter(filters.imported).value()
```

from closures in that are in _filters object

Maybe someone has the idea, of how create the dynamically chaining in underscore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you wish to have a dynamic number of filters, that should be applied to the array, If so, you can extract the filters from the object with `_.values()`, and then iterate them using `_.every()`. If all filters return `true`, the order will be in the resulting array:

```
var filters = {
  shipped: function(order) {
    return order.get('is_shipped')
  },
  imported: function(order) {
    return order.get('is_imported')
  }
};

var filtersArray = _.values(filters);

var result = _.filter(orders, function(order) {
  return _.every(filters, function(filter) {
    return filter(order);
  });
});
```

You can also do the filtering without underscore:

```
var filters = {
  shipped: function(order) {
    return order.get('is_shipped')
  },
  imported: function(order) {
    return order.get('is_imported')
  }
};

var filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);

var result = orders.filter(function(order) {
  return filterKeys.every(function(key) {
    return filter[key](order);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! That is exactly I was looking for :)